# Sql group by and join issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

Perhaps just because I have had insufficient sleep this weekend, but I cannot seem to fix it.
I have these tables:

- Products (PK Productid with fk categoryid)
- ShippedProducts (PK ShippedProductsID with FK ShipmentID and fk productid)
- Shipments (PK ShipmentID with FK InvoiceID)
- Invoices (PK InvoiceID with FK CustomerID)
- Customers (PK CustomerID with FK CountryId)
- Countries (PK CountryID)

sorry, no other way to explain the schema. Please let me know if I can give a better overview for the data structure.

Here is my SQL (database is Microsoft SQL server 2008)

```
SELECT  countries.countryid, 
        countryname, 
        isnull(round(sum(InvoiceTotal), 2),0) as TotalInvoice,
        count(invoices.invoiceid) as nrOfInvoices,
        count(shipments.shipmentid) as nrOfShipments
FROM    INVOICES
inner join customers on invoices.CustomerID = customers.customerid
inner join countries on customers.CountryID = COUNTRIES.CountryID 
inner join shipments on shipments.invoiceid = invoices.invoiceid
inner join ShippedProducts on ShippedProducts.ShipmentID = shipments.ShipmentID
group by countryname, COUNTRIES.CountryID, CurrencyName, CURRENCIES.CurrencyID
```

If I comment out the last inner join (with shippedproducts) I get the right number of invoices etc. but when I inner join the shippedproducts the count does not count the invoiceid but somehow the number of productrows from the shipment.
If I add more things to the group by, It does not group anymore by the country and I have a row for each invoice and shipment etc.
I somehow do not manage to see my mistake this monday. Perhaps I just need more coffee.

Comment: Why do you need that join?   Are you getting any columns from that table?

Comment: Yes, wanted `count(ShippedProducts.ShipmentProductsID) as totalProd`

Comment: Try `count(distinct invoices.invoiceid) as nrOfInvoices`.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a windowing function to do this without a group by.  Like this

```
SELECT
  countries.countryid, 
  countryname, 
  isnull(round(sum(InvoiceTotal) over (partition by invoice.invoiceID), 2),0) 
     as TotalInvoice,
  count(invoices.invoiceid) 
     over (partition by countries.countryid) as nrOfInvoicesPerCountry,
  count(shipments.shipmentid) over (partition by coutries.countryid) 
     as nrOfShipments
FROM INVOICES
inner join customers on invoices.CustomerID = customers.customerid
inner join countries on customers.CountryID = COUNTRIES.CountryID 
inner join shipments on shipments.invoiceid = invoices.invoiceid
inner join ShippedProducts on ShippedProducts.ShipmentID = shipments.ShipmentID
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your problem is joining on a 1 to many relationship.

I think you should either put your count of `ShippedProducts.ShipmentProductsID` into a subselect in your select statement. Something like this perhaps..

```
select countries.countryid, 
    countryname, 
    isnull(round(sum(InvoiceTotal), 2),0) as totalInvoice,
    count(invoices.invoiceid) as nrOfInvoices,
    count(shipments.shipmentid) as nrOfShipments
    (select count shipmentproductsid from shipmentproducts where shipmentproducts.shipmentid = shipments.shipmentID)  as totalProd 
from invoices
    inner join customers on invoices.customerid = customers.customerid
    inner join countries on customers.countryid = countries.countryid
    inner join shipments on shipments.invoiceid = invoices.invoiceid    
group by countryname, countries.countryid , currencyname, currencies.currencyid
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that before and it told me to add `shipmentid` to the group by. which result that it does not group anymore on country. I will have several rows with the same country, but different shipmentids